# Reflections of glass problem copying photo

Tags: lighting, glass

I have to copy a photograph using Blender. What I have so far is attached. Photo on the Left, my render on the right. The main thing at the moment I'm having issues with is the base of the wine glass. The reflections are mostly missing. I've tried turning caustics on but that made little difference. The lighting is accurate, I know this because I had detailed instruction from the original photographer. Can anyone help please?

[image: Wine glasses]

Comment: Possibly number of bounces limit...? Try increasing Light Path Total and/or Transmission bounces (assuming Cycles)

Comment: "Possibly number of bounces limit...? Try increasing Light Path Total and/or Transmission bounces (assuming Cycles) – Rich Sedman" Thank you, but no, just tried bumping Transmission bounces to 36 and still the same result.

Comment: Is the glass (bottom face of the glass) actually in contact (occupying the same space) as the "tablecloth" below it? Any overlapping faces/objects in cycles will result in black areas where there should be transparency. If the bottom of the glass and the tablecloth are overlapping in your project, try moving the glass "upwards" on the Z-Axis even as little as .001 units.

Comment: Flattened the cloth and lifted the glass. Didn't work :(